Package existing 3rd Parties in seperate C++20 modules
I'm trying to use modules to speed up our windows builds a little bit.
From my first impressions C++20 Modules are definitely faster than PCH (atleast on windows).
Currently I'm only focussed on windows with latest MSVC 17 and latest CMake. I'm also using import std which is only available on C++23.
I know that these features are cutting edge, but this is a first try and not used in any productive system. (I need to preserve backwards compatibility though with "classic" includes)
Since MSVC17 has a good working module support and CMake has added the import std in their latest version I'd like to give it a try.
Now the problems I have encountered are name clashes.
So basically since I use import std; I would like to avoid all stl includes.
Modifying our code is not a big deal, the real challenge is packaging existing 3rd Parties (like fmt and nlohmann_json) into modules since their headers include multiple std headers (which are causing name clashes with import std;)
I have watched Daniela Engert talks about C++20 modules from some CppCons and checked out her examples.
https://github.com/DanielaE/asio/tree/d212efd69aedf221475dc2434c45a6baeee10d16/asio/module
She basically included the 3rd party header within the export. However this did not work for me.
// Global module fragment where #includes can happen
module;

//inlcuded headers will not be exported to the client


// first thing after the Global module fragment must be a module command
export module nlohmann_json;

extern "C++"
{
  export
  {
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
  }
}


module: private;
//possbile to include headers here, but they will not be exported to the client

This is my test programm
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
import nlohmann_json;
TEST(CxxModuleTest, nlohman_json)
{
  nlohmann::json j = {
  {"pi", 3.141},
  {"happy", true},
  {"name", "Niels"},
  {"nothing", nullptr},
  {"answer", {
    {"everything", 42}
  }},
  {"list", {1, 0, 2}},
  {"object", {
    {"currency", "USD"},
    {"value", 42.99}
  }}
  };

  EXPECT_EQ(j["pi"], 3.141);
  EXPECT_EQ(j["happy"], true);
  EXPECT_EQ(j["name"], "Niels");
  EXPECT_EQ(j["nothing"], nullptr);
  EXPECT_EQ(j["answer"]["everything"], 42);
  EXPECT_EQ(j["list"][0], 1);
  EXPECT_EQ(j["list"][1], 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(j["list"][2], 2);
  EXPECT_EQ(j["object"]["currency"], "USD");
  EXPECT_EQ(j["object"]["value"], 42.99);
}

However this does not compile. I'm getting
'#include <filename>' in the purview of module 'module-name-1' appears erroneous. Consider moving that directive before the module declaration, or replace the textual inclusion with 'import <filename>;'.

I ended up with this
// Global module fragment where #includes can happen
module;

//inlcuded headers will not be exported to the client
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

// first thing after the Global module fragment must be a module command
export module nlohmann_json;

export
{
  namespace nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail
  {
    using ::nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::json_sax_dom_callback_parser;
    using ::nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::json_sax_dom_parser;
  }

  namespace nlohmann
  {

    using ::nlohmann::basic_json;
    using ::nlohmann::json;
    using ::nlohmann::json_sax;
    using ::nlohmann::detail::json_sax_dom_parser;
    using ::nlohmann::detail::json_sax_dom_callback_parser;
  }
}


module: private;
//possbile to include headers here, but they will not be exported to the client

However this is a try and error. I need to add all types until the program compiles.
=>My question:
Is there a better (more generic) way?
thx guys for your help :)

You can export import a header file in the module interface unit to export all symbols in it.
// in .ixx file, module interface unit
export module nlohmann_json;

export import <nlohmann/json.hpp>;

// in .cpp file
import nlohmann_json;
// use nlohmann/json here

This is probably the easiest way to port legacy headers to modules until you can write a proper module interface unit for them where you only export the components you actually need.
Note that limiting the exported symbols in the future will be a breaking API change, so library authors shouldn't be doing this too often.
CMakeLists.txt example:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(JSON_BuildTests OFF CACHE INTERNAL "")

project(cpp_json)

add_subdirectory(external/json)  # nlohmann_json directory

add_executable(cpp_json main.cpp)

target_sources(cpp_json
  PUBLIC
    FILE_SET modules TYPE CXX_MODULES
      BASE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/module
      FILES module/nlohmann_json.ixx
)
target_link_libraries(cpp_json PUBLIC nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)

since the .ixx file doesn't need .cpp files you can create an interface library for it.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(JSON_BuildTests OFF CACHE INTERNAL "")

project(cpp_json)

add_subdirectory(external/json)  # nlohmann_json directory

add_library(nlohmann_json_interface)  # linking target for import

target_sources(nlohmann_json_interface
  PUBLIC
    FILE_SET modules TYPE CXX_MODULES
      BASE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/module
      FILES module/nlohmann_json.ixx
)
target_link_libraries(nlohmann_json_interface PUBLIC nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)

add_executable(cpp_json main.cpp)
# only need my interface target
target_link_libraries(cpp_json nlohmann_json_interface)


hey thxs for your answer. Unfortuanately this gives me the compiler error header unit nlohmann/json.hpp>; not found.
Am I missing something?

Of course you are right,I need to export all symbols otherwise I'll break my API. That's why I don't like my approach. However I haven't found another working way :(

@JHeni it is working fine on my machine using Visual studio 17.11.0 preview 2, are you sure whichever target has this .ixx file is also using target_link_libraries(something PUBLIC nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json) so that the include directories are properly set ?

@JHeni it also works on Visual studio 17.9.6, i added the CMakeLists.txt

sorry. It looks like I'm doing something wrong. I created a new blank cmake project and copied the first cmake snippet (Module and main within the same target) and I'm still getting hederunit for nlohmann/json.hpp not found
I had to remove
add_subdirectory(external/json)  # nlohmann_json directory
In my dummy project external/json is a header only folder and not a seperate cmake module

@JHeni if you use the header only library you should have target_include_directories(cpp_json PUBLIC external/json) or something like that to add the include directory of the header to be publicly accessible to cmake.

yeah i did that. (I first missed it and got a file not found error ;))  Are you guys really using a cmake project or a VS soltuion? export import <nlohmann/json.hpp>; isn't that a header unit? Header units do not seam to be supported by Cmake yet (VS on the other hand has header unit support)

@JHeni i am building with cd build then cmake .. then cmake --build . , could you update your version of visual studio ? In the toolbar use Help -> check for updates, you can find the entire project in this zip file https://file.io/6Zgfnh3L85YU , if it fails on your device then you have a problem with your visual studio installation

ah thx for the clarification. When I'm building from CLI it works too. When I am importing this project as a cmake project in VS it does not work :O
